# Replicating and Load Balancing between Ray Actors

Tags: python, distributed-computing, ray

If an actor becomes a bottleneck for a Ray application, is there a way to replicate it and using the load balancing logic?

Using an actor as a service (by passing actor handles into Ray tasks), it creates use cases s.t.; instead of the whole state/data belonging to an actor, that state could be split  into multiple actors in favor of the availability.

Is there a built-in tool, a common practice or a workaround for that, or does this have to be handled manually?

Comment: What is *"s.t."* in *"...creates use cases s.t. instead..."*?

Comment: It is an abbreviation for "such that".

Answer (score 1):

While I could not find a built-in way to replicate a bottleneck actor (that is used as a service by other Ray components) dynamically during runtime, it turns out the round robin logic can be used for load balancing. While passing replicated actors' handles to Ray tasks, actors can be distributed with round robin load balancing in mind.

E.g., if we have 150 Ray tasks (or worker actors) that will use 15 state holder actors' handles, we could basically;

```
StateHolderActors = [StateHolder.remote() for _ in range(15)]

futures = [task.remote(StateHolderActors[i % 15], *args) for i in range(150)]
```